# Usage of "to find out"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, word-usage, infinitives

> Your father climbed to some rough rocks near the coast to find out that under the rocks, our friend Lake lies severely wounded.

Is this usage of "to find something by chance (as a result of climbing)" correct?

Comment: The whole sentence confuses me; I can't imagine a native speaker saying or writing this. The importance of the dependent clause is simply not compatible with all the elaboration in first part of the sentence.

Comment: Without knowing the context, any alternative is questionable. However, in most circumstances I would expect the statement to be two sentences: "Our friend Lake was severely wounded. Your father found him under some rough rocks near the coast."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is essentially seeking "writing advice"

Comment: To me, _I found out_ means either _I discovered by some effort_ or _I discovered something that I was not supposed to know_. But I noticed in the memoirs of Richard Feinman a different use: just _discovered_. I don't know whether this is a UK/US difference, or an idiosyncracy of Feinman's (or mine).

Comment: At any rate, what is not correct is your putting whitespaces inside the parentheses. (Where have you even seen that? That is never, ever done. They go outside.) Likewise for your tagging the question "gerund". There is not a single gerund in the entire sentence.

Comment: @Colin 'found out' can have the 'by digging' sense in the UK, but often just has the 'came by the information' sense. Context usually disambiguates. However, with 'Your father climbed to some rough rocks near the coast to find out that under the rocks' I'd say that 'to find out that' (which can't mean 'in order to find out ...') is too garden-pathy to be used. 'To find' or 'to discover' (with the 'only' if desired) would be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it is written could be improved. It does suggest that 'your father' happened upon the discovery by chance. But that is largely due to the circumstances of this particular account.

Consider for a moment *He looked up to see a dodo flying backwards*.

It could mean either that he had just been told there was a dodo flying backwards, so he looked up to see it. But it could also mean that he looked up (for other reasons) and lo and behold there was a dodo flying backwards.

To be absolutely clear that something was discovered by chance you need to say something like:

*He looked up, and what should he see but a dodo flying backwards*. You can replace *'and what should he see'* with many other phrases, such as *'to his great surprise'*, *'to his utter astonishment'*, etc.

You can also say *He looked up, only to see a dodo flying backwards*. This last does convey the idea that it was a discovery on his part. It would be a good way of dealing with your example:

*Your father climbed to some rough rocks near the coast, only to find that under those rocks our friend Lake lay severely wounded*

Comment: Yes, *only to find* eliminates the ambiguity in the original, which allows the interpretation that he climbed the rocks *in order to find* his friend.

Comment: Yes; '[_only_] to find [that] ...' meaning 'and found [that] [_surprise, surprise!_] ... is rather dated. The meaning 'in order to' is far more common nowadays. The function and semantics of the word 'only' here (if included) present quite a challenge. I'd have it as a commentary pragmatic marker signalling the unexpectedness of the thing he happened to see (as you imply).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'He opened the door of the stable only to find that the horse was gone'. I don't see how that can possibly mean 'in order to find the horse was gone'.

Comment: With 'only', the 'in order to' meaning is of course precluded. As it is when the verb doesn't make sense with a purpose clause (*'in order to find that'). But the non-purpose sense of 'V1-ed [+ adverb etc] to V2' is not very common in conversation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But your previous but one comment, unless I read you incorrectly, suggested that 'only to find that' nowadays meant 'in order to find that'. As regards your last comment I agree what you say about conversation, but we are not only talking about conversation are we.

Comment: No; it's the restrictions of formatting in 'comments' here. Leaving aside how one _should_ interpret additions in square brackets, I was just trying to show that the 'to find that' meaning 'and found that', 'to find' meaning 'and found', and the slightly different 'only to find that' meaning 'and found that (!)' are not used anywhere near as often as the 'to find' meaning 'in order to find'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But how do you indicate that something was found by surprise and without looking for it? 'I opened the door of the house only to see a great ape sitting on the stairs', indicates it all happened by surprise. '...in order to see great ape...' would have a completely different meaning, wouldn't it?

Comment: (1) I'm not implying it's wrong! (2)[These Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=only+to+see+a%2Cto+see+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conly%20to%20see%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20see%20a%3B%2Cc0) at least suggest it's not used all that often (I'd say at least semi-formal register). (3) "I opened the door, and _what do you think I found!?_ // _guess what I saw?_ ..." sound far more colloquial to me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree. But going back to the OP's post, I merely suggested 'only to find' for that particular sentence; which appeared to me to be part of a written account.

Comment: I agreed with your answer! I upvoted it! I'd have given largely the same one! But I'd have added – er – what I _have_ added. S'(partly) wot comments are for.